# XAML Named element not found by FindName

Tags: wpf, vb.net, silverlight, xaml, findname

I am having problems finding an named object declared in XAML in my codebehind file.

I want to initalize a ViewModel from inside my View. However I also need a reference to the ViewModel in my code behind file (basically for navigation support, handling events, etc. that I cannot do easily from my ViewModel)

```
<navigation:Page.DataContext>
    <vm:JobsViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</navigation:Page.DataContext>
```

However I get a null reference exception when I'm trying to access the ViewModel in my code behind:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
        ViewModel.Initalize() '<-- Exception here
    End Sub
```

Some more research shows that the `FindName` call for "ViewModel" in `InitalizeComponent` returns null. I tried reading up on XAML namescopes etc. but as far as I see, this should be a simple case and just work, no?

Any pointers as to why this fails would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `JobsViewModel` is not part of the visual tree, so `FindName` doesn't find it. You can retrieve it through the `DataContext` property instead.

Comment: As I understand the documentation from FindName it searches the XAML tree, which is not necessarily the same as the Visual Tree. And I think that I saw samples using x:Name on e.g. a Brush property and then later refering to it using Binding.ElementName, which I would assume works like FindName...

Comment: And yes, DataContext would work, but I'm interested in understanding how x:Name, FindName(, ElementName) work together for future reference and to avoid more mistakes.

Comment: @aKzenT, have a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/23/of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-wpf.aspx), it's the best I've seen on the subject

Comment: Thanks, it explains very nicely the difference between logical and visual tree in WPF. However in MSDN it says that FindName works on the XAML Namescope which should be independent from this. Also when I set the Background property of the Page to a SolidColorBrush and give this brush a name it will show up in FindName, so where is the difference? Why doesn't it work for DataContext?